# Split xml elements into two without affecting other tags using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am converting one xml to other xml. I am struggle in splitting this element.

```
<div class="cont">      (23)(A) “Component” means a uniquely identifiable <i>homogeneous material</b>, part, piece, <u>assembly</u>, is a necessary or intended element of a consumer product.</div>
```

Should be

```
<div class="li1">(23)</p>
<div class="li2">(A) “Component” means a uniquely identifiable <i>homogeneous material</i>, part, piece, <u>assembly</u>, is a necessary or intended element of a consumer product.</div>
```

I tried using below code. But the `<i>` and `<u>` are missing in the output.

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="^&#x0a;*\s*(\([0-9]+\))(\([A]+\)(.+))">
                    <xsl:matching-substring>
                        <div class="li2"><xsl:copy-of select="regex-group(1)"></xsl:copy-of></div>
                        <div class="li2" par="inline"><xsl:copy-of select="regex-group(2)"></xsl:copy-of></div>
                    </xsl:matching-substring>
                 </xsl:analyze-string>
```

My output is

```
<div class="li1">(23)</p>
    <div class="li2">(A) “Component” means a uniquely identifiable homogeneous material, part, piece, assembly, is a necessary or intended element of a consumer product.</div>
```

Please someone help me to solve this

Comment: So what kind of content do you expect for `div[@class = 'cont']`? Will it always start with a text node that matches your first regexp part of white space followed by digits inside of `()`?

Comment: yes the text will starts with regexp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it suffices to split up the text node child with analyze-string and then wrap the second part and any following nodes into the second result div:

```
  <xsl:template match="div[@class = 'cont']">
      <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
      <xsl:analyze-string select="node()[1]" regex="^&#x0a;*\s*(\([0-9]+\))">
          <xsl:matching-substring>
              <div class="li2">
                  <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
              </div>
          </xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:non-matching-substring>
              <div class="li2" par="inline">
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="tail($this/node())"/>
              </div>
          </xsl:non-matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, but tail() function is available in version 3.0. Can you give solution in 2.0 version

Comment: Use `$this/node()[position() gt 1]`